# How to skip IAM change confirmation during a cdk deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

When deploying any changes with the CDK that require IAM policy updates, you get the following message:

`This deployment will make potentially sensitive changes according to your current security approval level`

which is followed by the list of policy changes to be made and then a confirmation dialog. In general I think this is a good thing to have, but unfortunately it makes automating deployments difficult.

Is there a hidden flag or environment variable that can be set to skip this confirmation? Something like Terraform's `-auto-approve` flag.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following flag on the `cdk deploy` command can be used to skip this confirmation.

```
--require-approval never
```

This is documented on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/tools.html#cli). The full list of options can also be found by running `cdk deploy --help`