# Aws CDK skip IAM Statement Changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

Here is a role I already declared with a policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
              "sqs:DeleteMessage",
              "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
              "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
              "sqs:GetQueueUrl"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:<my-account>:my-prefix-*"
      }
   ]
}
```

When I deploy manually my queue and Lambda (with Trigger) everything is OK (and it is working as expected). However when I deploy with CDK it tries to add a new inline policy which looks exactly the same (without wildcards):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
              "sqs:DeleteMessage",
              "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
              "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
              "sqs:GetQueueUrl"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-3:<my-account>:my-prefix-MYRESOURCE-CREATED"
      }
   ]
}
```

My questions:

- Why CDK do not detect that policy is the same ?
- If it is working as design, is there a way to not include IAM changes ?

I am not referencing to [How to skip IAM change confirmation during a cdk deploy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937339/how-to-skip-iam-change-confirmation-during-a-cdk-deploy) where user wants an auto approval.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are passing a `role` parameter into your Lambda [`Function`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.Function.html).

If you don't want CDK to automatically add inline policies to this role, you may want to use [`.without_policy_updates()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-iam.Role.html#withoutwbrpolicywbrupdates):

> Use the object returned by this method if you want this Role to be used by a construct without it automatically updating the Role’s Policies.
>
> If you do, you are responsible for adding the correct statements to the Role’s policies yourself.